# How do I deduplicate Drupal taxonomies on a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, duplication, drupal

## Background

I've been tasked with deduplicating a Drupal 7 install. There are about 15 thousand articles published, which have been imported directly into the database using some custom in-house migration script, rather than via the usual Drupal workflow.

Every article has a certain taxonomy item associated with it. There are around 315 different possible values for this taxonomy, and it is *always* present on all articles, having been inserted using the migration script.

## Issues

However, it appers that some data duplication happened during the initial import. There are 15020 rows in the `node` table, and 11751 rows in the `taxonomy_term_data` table when filtered with the corresponding `vid` for this taxonomy (2).

I ran the following SQL query to try to find repetitions

```
SELECT name, count(name) as repetitions 
FROM taxonomy_term_data 
WHERE vid = 2 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY repetitions desc, name;
```

The result shows 335 rows, which is, coincidentally, the expected amount of unique terms. The "repetitions" column indicates nearly every term shows up dozens or even hundreds of times.

## Database structure

The table `node` contains the articles, the table `taxonomy_term_data` holds the taxonomies and the table `taxonomy_index` holds the relationship between each.

### `node` table

```
  nid serial NOT NULL, -- The primary identifier for a node.
  vid bigint, -- The current node_revision.vid version identifier.
  type character varying(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying, -- The node_type.type of this node.
  language character varying(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying, -- The languages.language of this node.
  title character varying(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying, -- The title of this node, always treated as non-markup plain text.
  uid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, -- The users.uid that owns this node; initially, this is the user that created it.
  status integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, -- Boolean indicating whether the node is published (visible to non-administrators).
  created integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, -- The Unix timestamp when the node was created.
  changed integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, -- The Unix timestamp when the node was most recently saved.
  comment integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, -- Whether comments are allowed on this node: 0 = no, 1 = closed (read only), 2 = open (read/write).
  promote integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, -- Boolean indicating whether the node should be displayed on the front page.
  sticky integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, -- Boolean indicating whether the node should be displayed at the top of lists in which it appears.
  tnid bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, -- The translation set id for this node, which equals the node id of the source post in each set.
  translate integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, -- A boolean indicating whether this translation page needs to be updated.
  CONSTRAINT node_pkey PRIMARY KEY (nid),
  CONSTRAINT node_vid_key UNIQUE (vid),
  CONSTRAINT node_nid_check CHECK (nid >= 0),
  CONSTRAINT node_tnid_check CHECK (tnid >= 0),
  CONSTRAINT node_vid_check CHECK (vid >= 0)
```

### `taxonomy_term_data` table

```
  tid serial NOT NULL, -- Primary Key: Unique term ID.
  vid bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, -- The taxonomy_vocabulary.vid of the vocabulary to which the term is assigned.
  name character varying(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying, -- The term name.
  description text, -- A description of the term.
  format character varying(255), -- The filter_format.format of the description.
  weight integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, -- The weight of this term in relation to other terms.
  CONSTRAINT taxonomy_term_data_pkey PRIMARY KEY (tid),
  CONSTRAINT taxonomy_term_data_tid_check CHECK (tid >= 0),
  CONSTRAINT taxonomy_term_data_vid_check CHECK (vid >= 0)
```

### `taxonomy_index` table

```
  nid bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, -- The node.nid this record tracks.
  tid bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, -- The term ID.
  sticky smallint DEFAULT 0, -- Boolean indicating whether the node is sticky.
  created integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, -- The Unix timestamp when the node was created.
  weight integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, -- A user-defined weight for each node in its respective category.
  CONSTRAINT taxonomy_index_nid_check CHECK (nid >= 0),
  CONSTRAINT taxonomy_index_tid_check CHECK (tid >= 0)
```

## What I need

- A way to determine if any of the repeated `taxonomy_term_data` is actually referenced in `taxonomy_index`.
- A way to, if necessary, set all occurrences in `taxonomy_index` to point to just one of each repeated `taxonomy_term_data`
- Finally, a way to delete all the `taxonomy_term_data` entries not in use in `taxonomy_index`.

I suppose one or more well-written queries would do the trick, but my SQL knowledge is terribly low.